# What are the alternatives to OR'ing multiple value options in an IF clause?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is there any c# syntax that would make this if statement cleaner/shorter?

```
if (token == "(" || token == ")" || token == "+" || token == "-" || token == "*" || token == "/")
{
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
// create a string with the valid chars
var tokens = "()+-*/";

// this will call the Contains method of the String class
if(tokens.Contains(token))
{
     //do something
}
```

Or with an array: *(This way you can validate on multiple chars within a match. (not included on this example))*

```
// create an array with the valid strings
var tokens = new [] { "(", ")", "+", "-", "*", "/" };

// this will call Contains method of the Enumerable class
if(tokens.Contains(token))
{
     //do something
}
```

Comment: Suppose `token == "()"` (not tokens), in that condition your above code will fail from what question is asked.

Comment: That's a good point, but I'd stop at this.. building parsers is a little more complicated than a simple "how to short this IF" question

Comment: The OP does not ask for multiple matches within a token.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, create a character array of the desired tokens and check if `token` exists in that array.

Comment: This is the solution i would go for, in any language that has some "string contains in given array" method built in.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so bad the way it is, especially if you write the `if` to span more than one line. Note that this is a candidate for `switch`ing on *characters*, not one character *strings*. Sometimes the old-fashioned ways are still the best ways and I think this is one of those cases.

Avoid tricks that involve coercing into a container. Such techniques can be ruinously expensive performance-wise, are unnecessarily contrived, and often end up being less clear.

Answer (score 1):

With Switch statement as shown below you can make it cleaner and shorter.

```
switch (token)
            {
                case "(":
                case ")":
                case "+":
                case "-":
                case "*":
                case "/":
                    //do something
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: Best answer in my opinion. As this will not match "()" as you say.

Answer (score -1):

how about

```
String validstr= "()+-*/";

    if(validstr.Contains(token))
    {
     // do something
    }
```

Comment: I think you got it backwards? Should be validstr.Contains(token)

Comment: Yes they did. A touchstone for the fact that these modern ways are surprisingly obfuscating.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a variable (or an array) that store all of the available tokens, I choose to detect if the provided candidate's length is 1 and exists in the string

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output"),
  Tokens = "()+-*/",
  TestTokens = "a1()+-*/\\";

for (var i = 0; i < TestTokens.length; i++) {
  var Token = TestTokens.substr(i, 1); // Use TestTokens.String.Substring(i, 1); in C#
  output.innerHTML += "<br />Token: " + Token + ": " + (Token.length == 1 && Tokens.indexOf(Token) >= 0).toString();
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```